# PySide: How Could I trigger the current clicked QPushbutton, not other later added

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots, qpushbutton

I am new to PySide. In my program, I encountered a problem that when I click one button, it triggers other button later added. Thanks!

```
    self.addContentButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Add')
    self.addContentButton.clicked.connect(self.addContent)

    def addContent(self):
    '''
        slot to add a row that include a lineedit, combobox, two buttons
    '''
        self.contentTabHBoxWdgt = QtGui.QWidget()

        self.contentName = QtGui.QLineEdit('line edit')

        self.conetentTypeBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.conetentTypeBox.addItem('elem1')
        self.conetentTypeBox.addItem('elem2')

        self.contentSave = QtGui.QPushButton('save',parent = self.contentTabHBoxWdgt)
        self.contentSave.clicked.connect(self.contntSaveAct)

        self.contentDelete = QtGui.QPushButton('delete',parent=self.contentTabHBoxWdgt)
        self.contentDelete.clicked.connect(self.contntDel)

        self.contentTabHBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.contentTabHBox.addWidget(self.contentName)
        self.contentTabHBox.addWidget(self.conetentTypeBox)
        self.contentTabHBox.addWidget(self.contentSave)
        self.contentTabHBox.addWidget(self.contentDelete)

        self.contentTabHBoxWdgt.setLayout(self.contentTabHBox)

        self.contentTabVBox.addWidget(self.contentTabHBoxWdgt)

    def contntDel(self):
    '''
        slot to delete a row 
    '''
        msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox(QtGui.QMessageBox.Warning, '', 'Be sure to delete')
        okBttn = msgBox.addButton('Yes', QtGui.QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
        noBttn = msgBox.addButton('Cancel', QtGui.QMessageBox.RejectRole)
        ret = msgBox.exec_()
        if msgBox.clickedButton() == okBttn:
            self.contentTabVBox.removeWidget(self.contentDelete.parentWidget());
```

When I Add one row and click its delete button, it does not work as expected.While I add two or three row , I click one delete button , it remove one row that is not the clicked delete button belong to. How could I achieve this function. Ths!

Comment: How do you mean triggers another button? Does the first one not fire, or do they both fire? Can you add some more details?

Comment: oh, say I add three rows, if I click the contentDelete button of the first row, it trigger delete the last row, not the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you aren't really taking advantage of object oriented programming properly.

All rows in your example call the same instance of the method `contntDel`. This method uses `self.contentDelete` which always contains a reference to the last row added.

What you need to do is separate out everything related to a row to a new class. When you add a row, create a new instance of this class and pass in the `contentTabVBox`. That way each row (or instance of the new class you will write) will have it's own delete method.

Without a complete code example, I can't provide a complete solution, but this should give you a rough idea:

```
class MyRow(object):
    def __init__(self,contentTabVBox, rows):
        self.contentTabVBox = contentTabVBox
        self.my_list_of_rows = rows
        self.addContent()

    def addContent(self):
        # The code for your existing addContent method here

    def contntDel(self):
        # code from your existing contntDel function here
        # also add (if Ok button clicked):
            self.my_list_of_rows.remove(self)

class MyExistingClass(??whatever you have here normally??):
    def __init__(....):
        self.addContentButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Add')
        self.addContentButton.clicked.connect(self.addContent)
        self.my_list_of_rows = []

    def addContent(self):
        my_new_row = MyRow(self.contentTabVBox,self.my_list_of_rows)
        # You mustsave a reference to my_new_row in a list or else it will get garbage collected.
        self.my_list_of_rows.append(my_new_row)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! That worked well for me! I wrote all the code in one class!